# List comprehesion using a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have this dictionary:

```
 primes = {2: True, 3: True, 4: False, 5: True, 6: False, 7: True}
```

And I wanted to create a list with only the pair that are True. It would look like this:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

So I tried doing it this way:

```
primelist = [x for x, y in primes if y]
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close!  You just need to call the [`.items()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)<sup>1</sup> on the dictionary:

```
primelist = [x for x, y in primes.items() if y]
```

Iterating over a dictionary in Python yields only its keys, not keys and values as some might expect.  To get those, you call `.items()` to return an iterable of key/value pairs, which can then be unpacked into the names `x` and `y`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that this answer is in regard to Python 3.x.  In Python 2.x, you should call `.iteritems()` instead since the Python 2.x `.items()` method will build an unnecessary list.

Comment: I'm doing it in Python 3.x. It was a silly mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> filter(primes.get, primes)
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

(That's Python 2, for Python 3 you'd need to slap a `list(...)` around it.)

I speed-tested it now with the numbers up to one million. Averages of 100 runs:

```
Python 2.7.9:
0.0908 seconds for filter(primes.get, primes)
0.2372 seconds for [n for n, p in primes.items() if p]

Python 3.4.3:
0.1856 seconds for list(filter(primes.get, primes))
0.0953 seconds for [n for n, p in primes.items() if p]
```

References: [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Comment: WoW ... You answered using `filter` while I was adding that to mine! But hey your's is better as it does not have `lambda` ... Should have thought of that!!

Comment: `filter(primes.get, primes)` would probably be better.  You rarely need to access special methods directly.  But cool answer nonetheless. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Note the improvement that iCodez pointed out. And I just speedtested it, on Python 2 it's actually *faster* than the list comprehension. I didn't expect that.

Comment: Very cool answer. I'm just beginnig to learn Python and I'm really impressed of how expressive it can be!

Comment: Yeah! I realized that my answer is bad enuf now :'( ... Will delete it as it is redundant!

Comment: @BhargavRao Hehe, sorry :-) Didn't want to make you feel bad, just wanted to make sure I didn't "teach" you to use `__getitem__` here.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Naw, my answer was really redundant! So I deleted :D ... It is nite 2 am here, perhaps that's why my mind isn't workin to it's fullest extent :P

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `items`, and store off the `key` if the `value` is `True`

```
>>> [k for k,v in primes.items() if v]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```